# Swift: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT- Getting and displaying data from Firestore

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner trying to get the app to be able to post and see posts that are in Firebase. Every time I run this part of the app I get an error and the app crashes. Any help?

The error occurs on this line: let time = doc.document.data()["time"] as! Timestamp

(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

This is part of my code,

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase



class PostViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var posts : [PostModel] = []
    @Published var noPosts = false
    @Published var newPost = false
    @Published var updateId = ""
    
    
    init() {
        
        getAllPosts()
    }
    
    func getAllPosts(){
        
        
        ref.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            guard let docs = snap else{
                self.noPosts = true
                return
                
            }
            
            if docs.documentChanges.isEmpty{
                
                self.noPosts = true
                return
            }
            
            docs.documentChanges.forEach { (doc) in
                
                // Checking If Doc Added...
                if doc.type == .added{
                    
                    // Retrieving and appending...
                    
                    let title = doc.document.data()["title"] as! String
                    let time = doc.document.data()["time"] as! Timestamp
                    let pic = doc.document.data()["url"] as! String
                    let userRef = doc.document.data()["ref"] as! DocumentReference
```

Comment: Do you have an error in console? I guess that either `doc.document.data()["time"]` is `nil`, or is not a `Timestamp`, but since you used `!`, it mean crash in theses cases...

Comment: Nothing comes up in the error console however there are a few icons that come up, one being: time = (FIRTimestamp) 0 x 00000... and another

Comment: the other that is all zero's is userRef

Comment: Using ! is dangerous - you should protect your code by safely unwrapping optionals or use the nil coalescing operator `let title = doc.document.data()["title"] as? String ?? "No Title"`. In this case it's a possibility that one of the nodes being read in is missing `time` or it may be caps `Time`. You can step through the code line by line, inspecting that until just before it crashes.

Comment: @Jay okay, what would the time and userRef lines look like? I am getting an error when trying to fetch user data. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think storing a DocumentReference is a good idea, or even is a thing as it's not a supported [Data Type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) that can be stored in Firestore. You should be storing the documentID's of other documents you want to access as a string. I don't know how you're using TimeStamp but it could be `let ts = doc.document.data()["time"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())`. As an aside, I really like to leverage simpler calls `let msg = doc.get("msg")...` get the msg from the document - functionally the same, but simpler.

Comment: @Jay Okay thank you! I will give this a go.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the help, it's helped a lot. I am now getting an error when trying to get user data. I changed my fetchUser model but there is a line I am stuck on and I think this is the line that is causing the error. In my model the line is:  let uid = user.documentID. And when I try to get user data the line is:     fetchUser(uid: userRef.documentID) { (user) in ...  The error is: Value of type 'String' has no member 'documentID'. - Can you see an issue here?

Comment: Well, that's true, Swift Strings don't have documentID's! You're storing the documentID as a string itself so you don't need to get the documentID from it - it's already the documentID. So `let userRef = doc.document.data()["ref"] as! String` is probably what you want. In fact, I would probably clarify the var name to `let uid = doc.document.data()["uid"] as! String` since both the var, and what's stored in Firebase is the actual users uid (as a string).

Comment: @Jay On the line:  fetchUser(uid: uid.documentID) { (user) in - I am getting an error message "Value of type 'String' has no member 'documentID'". I assume this is because I'm already storing the documentID as a string. Do you know a way to fetch the user a different way? I am also getting an error on a line in my fetchUser Model: let uid = doc.document.data()["uid"] as! String - the error is: Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot?' has no member 'document' I assume this could be related. Thanks

Comment: I think my above comment explains the String issue. Please take a look. For clarity, this code does not fetch a User, it reads a Firebase document that contains data (some user data in this case). As far as the other part of your comment, I don't see that line in the question so I don't know how it's being used. I would say this `forEach { (doc)` should be `forEach { (diff)` as the diff tells you what kind of change it is and will then contain another property `diff.document.data()`